# Copper NPT male fitting: accepted practice to sweat to the inside?

Tags: plumbing, copper-tubing, soldering

My plumber did this and I'm finding it hard to search about, asking for my next project.

[Here's an example](https://www.supplyhouse.com/Jones-Stephens-G20004-3-4-Male-Hose-x-1-2-Male-Pipe-1-2-SWT-Brass-Garden-Hose-Adapter-78SWT): the 1/2" side of this fitting is 1/2" male NPT, but you can also sweat a 1/2" copper pipe to the inside.

I've seen other references to this practice but I'm just wanting to know if it's taught in trade schools?  Or is it regarded as a hack?

Comment: It is literally listed for that purpose.  Using a product according to its labeling and instructions may be a hack, but it's not an illegal one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not call it a hack it is more expensive and due to the metal thickness takes a bit longer to sweat but works fine. Possibly a little better as the brass will hold up better than a copper male fitting.

Answer (score 1):

Inexpensive 1/2" multi-turn valves with "washer" type seals with 1/2" MIP threads can be and often are sweated directly to 1/2" copper tubing. So the makers of these parts have long realized that this option could be made available if the inside was made the correct size for copper tubing.